# how to check with angular.js what is the type of an element

Tags: angularjs

I received an html node and store it as angularjs element:

```
var el=angular.element(e.target);
```

How can i check if that element is of type "textarea" or "input" without using jQuery?

Comment: Where are you using this? inside a directive? you can wrap text area in your own directive http://jsfiddle.net/LMq3M/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily find it by using :-

```
 el[0].tagName=="INPUT" or  el[0].tagName=="TEXTAREA"
```

Small example:-

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
    <textarea id="check"></textarea>
</div>
```

Controller:-

```
  var e1=angular.element(document.querySelector("#name"));
    var e2=angular.element(document.querySelector("#check"))
    console.log(e1[0].tagName);
    console.log(e2[0].tagName);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obmdh52t/1/)

Comment: Thanks @squiroid! I'm new to angular. Where can i find some documentation/tutorial about dealing with DOM elements in angular. e.g why does ngular.element(e.target) returns an array? what are in the other cells?

Comment: @amit this is simple jqlite or Jquery concept .Jquery or jqlite return the array of elements. So,to retrieve a single element from a jQuery object u need 0  index.Also, note that [0] will get you the DOM element, not a jQuery object. 
And angular.element is the alias for jquery or jqlite so it will also return the same things.

Answer (score 2):

A rather short answer is:

`el[0].tagName === 'TEXTAREA'`